# How to make a tag description required

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, forms

I'm pretty new to WordPress, but basically what I'm trying to achieve is to make a tag's description a required field on my custom theme for WordPress 4.5.2

I've tried three approaches, but all of them failed so if anyone WordPress expert out there could guide me would be nice.

### Approach #1

#### functions.php

I've tried to 'edit' the hook when the `edit_tag_form_fields` and `add_tag_form` hook is called, then modify via Javascript

```
function require_category_description(){
    require_once('includes/require_category_description.php');
}
add_action('edit_tag_form_fields', 'require_category_description');
add_action('add_tag_form', 'require_category_description');
```

#### require_category_description.php

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var description = jQuery('#tag-description');
        if(!description) description = jQuery('#description');

        if(description){
            description.parents('form').submit(function(){
                if(description.val().trim().length < 1){
                    console.log('Please enter a description...');
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

It was not working, the form was submitting even though the description field was empty, and above all, the console.log inside the event listener never happened. I've tried to log the description variable to make sure it's going inside the if case. Therefore, I assumed the form was never submitting, and the whole 'submission' is done via Ajax, on the button click.

### Approach #2

The `functions.php` remains the same as approach #1, but I've made some changes Javascript wise to target the button click event instead of the form submit event.

#### require_category_description.php

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var description = jQuery('#tag-description');
        if(!description) description = jQuery('#description');

        if(description){
            var button = description.parents('form').find('#submit');

            button.on('click', function(e){
                if(description.val().trim().length < 1)
                    console.log('Please enter a description...');

                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

The form is however still submitting, but this time, I see the console log message.

> Please enter a description...

My theory is that WordPress is binding an event to the button's click before my event, so it's processing the built-in event with Ajax before going to my custom click event.

### Approach #3

#### require_category_description.php

I've tried to unbind the click events from my button before adding my own click event.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var description = jQuery('#tag-description');
        if(!description) description = jQuery('#description');

        if(description){
            var button = description.parents('form').find('#submit');
            button.unbind('click');

            button.on('click', function(e){
                if(description.val().trim().length < 1)
                    console.log('Please enter a description...');

                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

The result is the same as approach #2. The form is still submitting, but I see the console log message.

Comment: its probably using the submit event rather than onclick! try unbind on the form to see can you remove the process action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit tag**:

When editing tag, WordPress call [`wp_update_term`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_term/#source-code). But there're no filters or AJAX call, so we must use [`get_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term/#source-code) which is called by `wp_update_term()`:

```
add_filter('get_post_tag', function($term, $tax)
{
    if ( isset($_POST['description']) && empty($_POST['description']) ) {
        return new \WP_Error('empty_term_name', __('Tag description cannot be empty!', 'text-domain'));
    } else {
        return $term;
    }
}, -1, 2);
```

We also need to update [`term_updated_message`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-admin/includes/edit-tag-messages.php#L49) to make the error clear:

```
add_filter('term_updated_messages', function($messages)
{
    $messages['post_tag'][5] = sprintf('<span style="color:#dc3232">%s</span>', __('Tag description cannot be empty!', 'text-domain'));
    return $messages;
});
```

Because WordPress [hardcoded the notice message](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-admin/edit-tag-form.php#L74) `div`, I used inline css to make the error look like a waring. Change it to your preference.

---

**Add new tag**:

The AJAX request calls [`wp_insert_term`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_term/) so we can use `pre_insert_term` filter. Try this in your `functions.php`

```
add_filter('pre_insert_term', function($term, $tax)
{
    if ( ('post_tag' === $tax) && isset($_POST['description']) && empty($_POST['description']) ) {
        return new \WP_Error('empty_term_name', __('Tag description cannot be empty!', 'text-domain'));
    } else {
        return $term;
    }
}, -1, 2);
```

Here I used the built-in `empty_term_name` error to show notice message but you should register your own one.

Also, take a look at [`wp_ajax_add_tag`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_ajax_add_tag/) to fully understand what we're doing.

#### Demo:

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! This is working for the ajax, but do you know which hook it is for the edit tag? Like when you're inside the tag itself.

Comment: @ChinLeung I have no idea why you also need to do it on `editing tag screen` when it's impossible to add a new tag without description. But i have updated the answer as you wished.

Comment: I need the editing tag screen because even though a user cannot add an empty tag... They can edit the tag and simply remove the description which would result with a tag with an empty description. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's Ajax so you cannot rely on `submit` event, here is a solution, how you can do.

All you want to do is include `form-required` class to the parent tag of the particular element, but there is kick on it. their `validateForm` check only on `input` tags not on `textarea` so I have implemented an idea, it works.

Try this

```
function put_admin_script() { ?>
<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var description = jQuery('#tag-description');
        if( !description ) { 
            description = jQuery('#description'); 
        }   
        if( description ) {
            description.after( $('<p style="visibility:hidden;" class="form-field form-required term-description-wrap"><input type="text" id="hidden-tag-desc" aria-required="true" value="" /></p>') );    
        }   
        description.keyup(function(){
            $("#hidden-tag-desc").val( $(this).val() ); 
        });

        jQuery("#addtag #submit").click(function(){
            console.log("Not empty"+description.val().trim().length);
            if( description.val().trim().length < 1 ) {
                description.css( "border", "solid 1px #dc3232" );
            } else {
                description.css( "border", "solid 1px #dddddd" );
            }                   
        }); 
    }); 

</script>
<?php 
}
add_action('admin_footer','put_admin_script');
```

Comment: Just tried it, the form is submitting, no console message. As I mentioned in the approach #1, I think the form itself is never submitting.

Comment: Oh, just now I too checked. It's Ajax

Comment: `wp-admin/js/tags.js` LN : 31, but it seems nothing we can do about it.

Comment: I would like to avoid making changes in the `wp-admin` because it would be overridden on the next version of WordPress update...

Comment: Found a solution, it works, but not a complete one, you can improve it anyway.

Comment: locate the base `tag` table in DB and try to locate the php file which verifies/validates the tag input and add it to the DB. Then in that php page, you need to add your new rule which dictates that tag description is mandatory.